# convert unique string to timestamp

Tags: php, html, mysql

i want to ask.

i grab data time from html, and i try to insert to my db.
when insert the format like "**Â  Â  8:16:25 PM 8/8/2017Â  Â**".
how i convert to timestamp format, because i want to range it.
i try to cut the string and make it utf8_decode or utf8_encode before insert. but when range i can't get the time. sorry for my english.

CODE :

```
$first = array('PM','/','AM');
$first2 = array('','-','');
$strreplacebegdate = str_replace($first,$first2, $tujuh);
$substrreplacebegdate1 = substr($strreplacebegdate,14,9);
$re = array(' ','?');
$re2 = array('','');
$strreplacebegdatelagi = str_replace($re,$re2, $substrreplacebegdate1);
$substrreplacebegdate2 = substr($strreplacebegdate,6,7);
$consubstringbegdate = $substrreplacebegdate1." ".$substrreplacebegdate2;
$timeenddate = strtotime($strreplacebegdatelagi);
$newformatbegdate = date('Y-m-d',$timeenddate);
```

output : 0000-00-00 00:00:00

Comment: I don't understand what is your question here? You want to clean the special chars *Â Â* or you want to calculate the difference b/w two dates?

Comment: sorry, my question is how to clean and convert it to date time..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its prefer you clean your date string. You can use regex in this case which only allows the certain character to pass and remove all the rest special and hidden chars.

```
$dirty_date = 'Â Â 8:16:25 PM 8/8/2017Â Â';
echo $date = preg_replace("/[^0-9a-zA-Z \/:\-]/", "", $dirty_date);
echo "\n";
echo $xtime = strtotime($date);
echo "\n";
echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s",$xtime);
```

Comment: wow it's working,  thank u Shoaib Zafar. u help me. very thanks

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `strtotime()` for this . As your date is in a different format.You can do it this way.

```
$str_time = 'Â Â 8:16:25 PM 8/8/2017Â Â';
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Â Â h:i:s a d/m/YÂ Â', $str_time);
$timestamp = $date->getTimestamp();
```

To read more about createFromFormat() . Visit this http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php . I hope this helped

Comment: I edited my answer. It will work with special chars also. Upvote if it helps.